# Do using queryset.count() caches the queryset?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm making some filtering in my endpoint, and one of the filters are only applied if the filtered queryset has more than 30 items.

```
yesterday_date = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)
if query_dict.get("active"):
    active_query = cleaned_query.filter(created_at__gt=yesterday_date)
    if active_query.count() > 30:
        cleaned_query = active_query
    else:
        cleaned_query = cleaned_query[:30]
```

My doubt is, will the .count() method already evaluates and caches the queryset or should I use len(queryset) to avoid another database hit in case it's bigger than 30?

Comment: The code looks quite strange, in case the number is greater than 30, you want all items, and otherwise you only want the first 30? That makes not much sense, since in the `else` case we already know that the number is less than 30, and thus slicing will not make any difference.

Comment: cleaned_query[:30] refers to another queryset.

Comment: There is a tool called ["Django Debug Toolbar"](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) that display how many times and which SQL queries were executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check django's docs about [When Querysets Are Evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

You'll see some information about counting...

> Note: If you only need to determine the number of records in the set
> (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s much more efficient to
> handle a count at the database level using SQL’s SELECT COUNT(*).
> Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason.

So a `count()` doesn't evaluate the set, whereas a `len()` does.